# One-2-One association and inheritance

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have an inheritance chain rooted A with sub types B and C. Next, I've an entity E like this:

```
public class E 
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public B B {get; set;}
    public C C {get; set;}
}
```

The navigation properties should be mapped to two one-2-one associations where E is the principal and B, C the dependents. This won't work because EF will use the value of E.Id as foreign keys for B and C, which will result in a duplicate key in the table A. It doesn't matter if I use TPT, TPC, or TPH.

If I would map it two two one-2-many associations and use distinct foreign keys in in E, i.e. with the mapping:

```
Entity<E>().HasRequired(x=>x.B).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x=>x.BId);
Entity<E>().HasRequired(x=>x.C).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x=>x.CId);
```

Than cascading delete wont work the in the right direction. That is E.B and E.C should be deleted when deleting e.

Any suggestions how to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

EF requires one mapped column per relationship (inheritance or association). You use one column up for the inheritance, therefore this column is not available in subclasses for association relationships (because you have to delete it from the subclasses).

You have 2 choices:

1. You can map E's 1-1 relationship with B and C by linking it to A (the superclass). But this is not an accurate representation of your model because the {B,C} relationships are to E, not to A.
2. Add another column to B and C that will be used for the associations to E. This new column should be unique and not null - because effectively you are creating another primary key. Both the existing primary key and the new column uniquely identify the record (for B or C). In the database, create the constraints between {B,C} and E using this new column. Now EF will be able to both represent the inheritance {A<-B, A<-C} and the association {E--B, E--C}